# How to Prevent EntityFramework from generating Multiple Foreign key relationships?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following model classes

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int MenuItemId { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public MenuType MenuType { get; set; }
}

public class Menu 
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuItem> BreakFast { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuItem> Lunch { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuItem> Snacks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuItem> Dinner { get; set; }
}
```

Now my understanding is that, according to EF Code First conventions it should generate the table

**MenuItem**

With **MenuItemId** as Primary key and **MenuId** as Foregin key, but becuase of something EF keeps generating duplicate Foreign Keys (extra 4 to be exact) for **MenuId** like MenuId1,2,3,4.

Is it becuase I'm having the `ICollection` of MenuItems ?

I don't understand why that should be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current setup will create four different relations to the `MenuItem` table. How about changing your model so that `Menu` has one collection of `ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems`. This will contain all `MenuItem`s, for all `MenuType`s.

You can then create properties for `BreakfastMenuItems`, `LunchMenuItems`, etc, filtering on `MenuItems` based on the `MenuType` property. Or alternatively, create a function `Menu.GetMenuItemsByType(MenuType menuType)` that will return the results that you want.

Comment: Will definitely give it a go!.. but is there anyway I can override this behaviour. I tried explicit associating the FK using both data annotations and th EF Fluent API, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is happening because of the collections in your menu class. From your model EF infers that one menu item can belong to BreakFast, Lunch, Snacks, Dinner lists in a menu. Any menu item can be in all/some/none of them. So this is the most straightforward design it generates.

However, the point of code first is.. coding first. Once you figure your model out then you can always make small changes.